# How to migrate Flutter project to null safety with all of its variable at once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an old project running on an old version of flutter (before null safety). To use `SharedPreferences` on Desktop(Windows) , I have to migrate my project.

Is it possible to migrate my project to a newer version without editing(adding null safety,edit the code to adapt to new syntax) my variables one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says:

> Most of the changes that your code needs to be null safe are easily predictable. For example, if a variable can be null, its type needs a ? suffix. A named parameter that shouldn’t be nullable needs to be marked required. You have two options for migrating: 1. Use the migration tool, which can make most of the easily predictable changes for you. 2.Migrate your code by hand.

Migration tools can be used to migrate at once.

For the case of dependencies:

> We strongly recommend migrating code in order, with the leaves of the dependency graph being migrated first. For example, if package C depends on package B, which depends on package A, then A should be migrated to null safety first, then B, then C.

[This](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) documentation gives step by step procedure to migrate the project to null safety.